# How can I make two carousel work on the same page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a page with 2 **carousels**. The **arrows** of the first one are controlling the second carousel and I don't know why. To be honest, I don't know a lot about all of this. Here's my code :

```
<div class="slider-container">
<div class="product-slider">
<div class="carousel">
<div class="slider">
<div class="slide"><a class="product-image" title="Le T-shirt &laquo; couture &raquo; &agrave; col montant" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/roxanne-noix-de-coco" target="_blank"> <img title="Magasinez notre coton &eacute;gyptien Karnak-Menoufi - Roxanne" alt="Magasinez notre coton &eacute;gyptien Karnak-Menoufi - Roxanne" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/roxanne_coconut_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="slide"><a class="product-image" title="Camisole en laine &laquo; deuxi&egrave;me peau &raquo;" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/gilda-ivoire" target="_blank"> <img title="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos extra-fine - Gilda" alt="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos extra-fine - Gilda" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/gilda_ivory_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="slide"><a class="product-image" title="Paris, la tuque en laine unisexe" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/paris-lynx" target="_self"> <img title="Magasinez nos accessoires en laine de m&eacute;rinos - Paris" alt="Magasinez nos accessoires en laine de m&eacute;rinos - Paris" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/paris_lynx_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="slide"><a class="product-image" title="Pull ballerine &agrave; d&eacute;tail point de croix" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/joyce-lychee" target="_blank"> <img title="Magasiner notre cachemire Alashan - Joyce" alt="Magasiner notre cachemire Alashan - Joyce" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/joyce_lychee_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="prev brands-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="next brands-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery('.product-slider > .carousel').iosSlider({
                    desktopClickDrag: true,
                    snapToChildren: true,
                    infiniteSlider: true,
                    navNextSelector: '.brands-arrow.next',
                    navPrevSelector: '.brands-arrow.prev',
                    lastSlideOffset: 3
                });
// ]]></script>
<div class="text-block">
<h4><a title="D&eacute;couvrez notre collection pour lui" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/men"><b>Pour lui</b></a></h4>
</div>
<div class="slider-container">
<div class="product-slider">
<div class="carousel">
<div class="slider">
<div class="slide"><a class="product-image" title="Le polo en jersey" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/hoche-chameau" target="_blank"> <img title="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Hoche" alt="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Hoche" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/hoche_camel_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="slide"><a class="product-image" title="La tuque en laine c&ocirc;tel&eacute;e" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/london-anthracite" target="_blank"> <img title="Magasinez notre collection d'accessoires - London" alt="Magasinez notre collection d'accessoires - London" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/london_anthracite_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="slide"><a class="product-image" title="Le basique pull &agrave; col roul&eacute;" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/louis-chameau" target="_blank"> <img title="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Louis" alt="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Louis" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/louis_camel_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="prev brands-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="next brands-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery('.product-slider > .carousel').iosSlider({
                    desktopClickDrag: true,
                    snapToChildren: true,
                    infiniteSlider: true,
                    navNextSelector: '.brands-arrow.next',
                    navPrevSelector: '.brands-arrow.prev',
                    lastSlideOffset: 3
                });
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change class name according to your slider

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="product-slider">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <a class="product-image" title="Le T-shirt &laquo; couture &raquo; &agrave; col montant" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/roxanne-noix-de-coco" target="_blank"> 
                        <img title="Magasinez notre coton &eacute;gyptien Karnak-Menoufi - Roxanne" alt="Magasinez notre coton &eacute;gyptien Karnak-Menoufi - Roxanne" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/roxanne_coconut_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a class="product-image" title="Camisole en laine &laquo; deuxi&egrave;me peau &raquo;" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/gilda-ivoire" target="_blank"> 
                        <img title="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos extra-fine - Gilda" alt="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos extra-fine - Gilda" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/gilda_ivory_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a class="product-image" title="Paris, la tuque en laine unisexe" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/paris-lynx" target="_self"> 
                        <img title="Magasinez nos accessoires en laine de m&eacute;rinos - Paris" alt="Magasinez nos accessoires en laine de m&eacute;rinos - Paris" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/paris_lynx_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a class="product-image" title="Pull ballerine &agrave; d&eacute;tail point de croix" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/joyce-lychee" target="_blank"> 
                        <img title="Magasiner notre cachemire Alashan - Joyce" alt="Magasiner notre cachemire Alashan - Joyce" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/joyce_lychee_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> 
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prev brands-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="next brands-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    jQuery('.product-slider > .carousel').iosSlider({
                        desktopClickDrag: true,
                        snapToChildren: true,
                        infiniteSlider: true,
                        navNextSelector: '.brands-arrow.next',
                        navPrevSelector: '.brands-arrow.prev',
                        lastSlideOffset: 3
                    });
    // ]]></script>
    <div class="text-block">
        <h4><a title="D&eacute;couvrez notre collection pour lui" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/men"><b>Pour lui</b></a></h4>
    </div>
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="product-slider1">
        <div class="carousel1">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <a class="product-image" title="Le polo en jersey" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/hoche-chameau" target="_blank"> 
                        <img title="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Hoche" alt="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Hoche" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/hoche_camel_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a class="product-image" title="La tuque en laine c&ocirc;tel&eacute;e" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/london-anthracite" target="_blank"> 
                        <img title="Magasinez notre collection d'accessoires - London" alt="Magasinez notre collection d'accessoires - London" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/london_anthracite_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a class="product-image" title="Le basique pull &agrave; col roul&eacute;" href="https://www.cavadesoi.com/fr/louis-chameau" target="_blank"> 
                        <img title="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Louis" alt="Magasinez notre laine de m&eacute;rinos 4 saisons - Louis" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/louis_camel_ajusted.jpg"}}" /> 
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prev brands-arrow1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="next brands-arrow1">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery('.product-slider > .carousel').iosSlider({
                    desktopClickDrag: true,
                    snapToChildren: true,
                    infiniteSlider: true,
                    navNextSelector: '.brands-arrow.next1',
                    navPrevSelector: '.brands-arrow.prev1',
                    lastSlideOffset: 3
                });
// ]]></script>
```